# Why does resolution not fit within display's screen

Tags: nvidia, display, hdmi, display-resolution

A 2013 [Samsung TV](https://www.samsung.com/us/video/tvs/UN55F7100AFXZA-specs) features 1920X1020 resolution.  It is driven by a NVIDIA [Nano](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetson-nano-developer-kit), outfitted with 18.04.  Why does said resolution not fit the TV?

The highest resolution that seems to properly fit the display is 1680X1050: the launch bar is 'pushed off' the left edge of the screen and the upper control indicator is pushed above the top of the display.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an overscan/underscan issue with the monitor.  I have the same but it is only slightly off.  To fix I run the following command.  Perhaps you can adapt it to your situation.

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+720, HDMI-0: 1360x768 +0+0 {viewportin=1360x768, viewportout=1312x748+25+10, ForceCompositionPipeline = On}"
```